# Implementing operator<< for a derived class

Tags: c++, class, operators, derived

So I have a base class (Shape) and three derived classes, Circle, Rectangle and Square (Square is derived from Rectangle) I'm attempting to implement operator<< which just calls the correct display function for what called it. However, I don't think I have the syntax correct. Here's a snippet--where have I gone wrong?

```
class Shape
{
     public:
     Shape(double w = 0, double h = 0, double r = 0)
     {
          width = w;
          height = h;
          radius = r;
     }

     virtual double area() = 0;
     virtual void display() = 0;

     protected:
     double width;
     double height;
     double radius;
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const Shape & s)
{
      s.display(out);
      return out;
}

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
     public:
     Rectangle(double w, double h) : Shape(w, h)
     {
     }

     virtual double area() { return width * height; }
     virtual void display() 
     {
        cout << "Width of rectangle: " << width << endl;
        cout << "Height of rectangle: " << height << endl;
        cout << "Area of rectangle: " << this->area() << endl;
     }
};
```

Comment: Obviously, `display()` should take `ostream & out` as a parameter, and write to `out`, but not `cout`.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `display` like this:

```
s.display( out );
```

But `display` is defined as:

```
vritual void display() = 0;
```

The function was declared and defined taking no parameters. It should take a reference to `std::ostream` as a parameter:

```
virtual void display(std::ostream &) = 0;
```

It should also be a `const` method as you're passing in a `const` object through the `operator <<` overload:

```
virtual void display(std::ostream &) const = 0;
```

<sub>Don't forget that in the definition of `display` you should be writing to the `ostream` object, not specifically `std::cout`.</sub>

Here is a compiling program on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/WFlnb2#view_edit_box).

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right, here is the working solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;

class Shape
{
     public:
     Shape(double w = 0, double h = 0, double r = 0)
     {
          width = w;
          height = h;
          radius = r;
     }

     virtual ~Shape() {} // Recommended!

     virtual double area() const = 0;
     virtual void display(ostream & out) const = 0;

     protected:
     double width;
     double height;
     double radius;
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const Shape & s)
{
      // Since `s` is `const`, then `display` method should be `const` too.
      s.display(out);
      return out;
}

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
     public:
     Rectangle(double w, double h) : Shape(w, h)
     {
     }

     virtual double area() const { return width * height; }
     virtual void display(ostream & out)  const
     {
        // Since `display` method is `const`, then `area` method should be
        // `const` too.
        out << "Width of rectangle: " << width << endl;
        out << "Height of rectangle: " << height << endl;
        out << "Area of rectangle: " << this->area() << endl;
     }
};


void main() {
    Rectangle r(1, 2);

    cout << r << endl;
}
```

Please, pay attention to the `const` qualifiers which enforce **[`const`-correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness)** of class methods. I've added some useful comments so that you can follow the logic smoothly. Take it as a rule of thumb, if the method does not modify class members, then you **should** declare it `const`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems here. Firstly, let's deal with the printing problem:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const Shape & s)
```

Here, you're passing a `const Shape`. This means you can only call `const` methods on the `s` you pass in. However, you haven't marked any of the methods in the base (or derived) class as `const`. Neither `area` nor `display` should change the state of the object. Secondly, you're trying to call `s.display(out)`, that is, passing an `ostream&` to `display`. The function signature you have doesn't reflect this. So putting that all together we get:

```
 virtual double area() const = 0;
 virtual void display(ostream& out) const = 0;
```

You've also got some other problems - a base class that doesn't declare a virtual destructor. If you're planning on using a class polymorphically, it **must** have a virtual destructor:

```
virtual ~Shape() { }
```

You also need to amend your methods in the derived class:

```
 double area() const { return width * height; }

 void display(ostream& out) const
 {
    out << "Width of rectangle: " << width << endl;
    out << "Height of rectangle: " << height << endl;
    out << "Area of rectangle: " << area() << endl;
 }
```

Note that `display` in `Rectangle` was always printing to `cout` beforehand.